# Laravel 5.5 Invisible Recaptcha not submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.5

I have a project in Laravel 5.5 and trying to implement Google Invisible Captcha but it keeps giving me this error on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _captchaForm.submit is not a function
```

The package I'm using is this one [enter link description here](https://github.com/albertcht/invisible-recaptcha)

The error is only on the js script, I already tried removing all js from the site for just this to show but neither way works.

I have a basic form

```
<form action="{{ route('post-contact') }}" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mensaje:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control height-120" placeholder="Mensaje" name="msg"></textarea>
                </div>
                @captcha('en')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn theme-btn" name="submit" type="submit">Enviar consulta</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I already enable debug on the console and it says that everything is binded as it should:

```
Checking element binding of _submitForm...
true
Checking element binding of _captchaForm...
true
Checking element binding of _captchaSubmit...
true
```

Any help will be appreciated, this is driving me nuts since yesterday.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My god I feel so stupid, the submit button had a name="submit" attribute breaking the js of the invisible captcha.

Just for anyone that might have this issue in the future, make sure you don't have an element with that name!

Comment: Haha that was exactly what happened to me. Thanks.

Comment: whats wrong with submit button having the name as submit... ?